# PHP APC multiple upload work incorrectly

Tags: php, upload, progress-bar, apc

I have a form:

```
<form onsubmit="upload_start()" target="upload_iframe" action="../blocks/file_tools/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS" value="<?php echo md5(rand().time()); ?>" />
        <input id="upload_files" name="upload_files[]" type="file" multiple accept="image/*" />
        <button id="addFilesButton" type="button" class="button button_gray" title="Добавить файлы"> + Добавить файл</button>
        <button class="button button_green" type="submit" title="Загрузить выбранный файлы">Загрузить</button>        
    </form>
```

In this file i read upload status:

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : 0;
$status =apc_fetch("upload_".$id);
header('Content-type: application/json');
print_r(apc_fetch("upload_".$id));
echo json_encode($status);
?>
```

I send via ajax

```
//Получаем статус загрузки фалов на сервер.
function upload_status()
{
    var id = $("input[name='APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS']").val();
    $.ajax(
    {
    url: '/blocks/file_tools/upload_status.php',    type: 'POST', dataType: 'HTML', charset: 'utf-8', async:false,
    data: ({id:id}),
    success: function(data) 
    {
          // some code
    }
   })   
   setTimeout(upload_status, 2000);
}
```

If I upload a file, the code works correctly
If you are loading multiple files, APC returns the status of loading only the last file in the array **upload_files[ ]**.
How to get the upload status of each file in the array **upload_files[ ]**?

Answer (score 1):

See http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.rfc1867:

> Note that the file upload tracking is not threadsafe at this point, so
>   new uploads that happen while a previous one is still going will
>   disable the tracking for the previous.

That basically means that upload progress can only be displayed for a single file at a time.

If you need it bad it is better to implement via webserver:

- http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule
- http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html ("Watching progress" section)